# Find files with no pdf extension where docx file exists. Run 'lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf' against those files

Tags: shell

Just wondering if there is a simpler, shorter, better command than the below:

**Files**:

```
123.pdf  
123.docx  
456.docx   <= Run 'lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf' against this file 
789.docx
789.pdf
'another file.docx' <= Run 'lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf' against this file
```

This command only works on files with no spaces:

```
ls *.docx | perl -nle '
  s/\.docx$/.pdf/; 
  print unless -e 
' | sed 's/\.pdf/\.docx/' | while read line ; do
  lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf $line ;
done
```

My filenames have no spaces so the command works for me.  But maybe others do need it to work for filenames with spaces

Comment: Or, as **GNU Parallel** is actually a Perl script and you seem to like Perl, you could try this `parallel '[ -f {.}.pdf ] || echo lowriter --headless --convert-to-pdf {}' ::: *.docx ` That says *"In parallel, do XXX for all .docx files, where XXX means, if the corresponding PDF doesn't exist, make it with `lowriter`"* Remove `echo` if it looks good.

Comment: With the echo it looks good.  Taking it out I get "Error in option: --convert-to-pdf"

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo - should be `--convert-to pdf` per your original question.

Comment: Brilliant !!!


`parallel '[ -f {.}.pdf ] || lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf {}' ::: *.docx`

Answer (score 1):

Summary from comments:

```
parallel '[ -f {.}.pdf ] || lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf {}' ::: *.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

> command only works on files with no spaces

Can you try put quotes around the last `$line`? Like this `.... --convert-to pdf "$line"` ?

As an alternative you could do everything in Perl like this:

```
for my $file (<*.docx>) {
    my $basename = $file =~ s/\.docx$//r;
    my $pdf_file = "${basename}.pdf";
    if (!-e $pdf_file) {
        system 'lowriter', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', $file;
    }
}
```